# batch file error

Tags: batch, python, automation, runtime-error

When I tried to run a batch file using gdal_calculate command. The following error occurs:

- batfile is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
- RuntimeError: D:\Sample\sample_file_.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
- RuntimeError: D:\Sample\sample_file_!Month!.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Is gdal_calculate not allowed to be use in batch process? Any idea?

Here is the script I am using:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "in_path=D:\Input"
set "out_path=D:\Output"
set "sample_path=D:\Sample"
set "proc_path=D:\Processed_Files"

md %out_path% 
md %proc_path%
cd /d "%in_path%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /on ????????*.tif ') do (
set "year=%%~na"
set "daynum=!year:~5,3!"
set "year=!year:~1,4!"

call ordinal.bat !year! !daynum! yy month dd
echo %%a matches to !yy!-!month!-!dd!

if !Month!==01 set Month=jan
if !Month!==02 set Month=feb
if !Month!==03 set Month=mar
if !Month!==04 set Month=apr
if !Month!==05 set Month=may
if !Month!==06 set Month=jun
if !Month!==07 set Month=jul
if !Month!==08 set Month=aug
if !Month!==09 set Month=sep
if !Month!==10 set Month=oct
if !Month!==11 set Month=nov
if !Month!==12 set Month=dec

gdal_calculate --out=%out_path%\%%a --calc="((image1-image2))" --image2=%sample_path%\sample_file_!Month!.tif --image1=%in_path%\%%a --extent=INTERSECT

)
echo done
goto :EOF

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:ordinal %year% %doy% yy mm dd
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, 2002-09-29. Version 1.0
::
:: Func: Returns a calendar date from an ISO 8601 Ordinal date.
::       For NT4/2K/XP.
:: 
:: Args: %1 year component to be converted, 4 digits (by val)
::       %2 day of year component to be converted, 001 to 366 (by val)
::       %3 var to receive year, 4 digits (by ref)
::       %4 var to receive month, 2 digits, 01 to 31 (by ref)
::       %5 var to receive day of month, 01 to 31 (by ref)
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a in ('echo/%1 %2') do set /a yy=%%a,o=1%%b%%1000
set /a z=14-1,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=1+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+1+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2432046,j+=o-1
set /a a=j+2432045,b=4*a+3,b/=146097,c=-b*146097,c/=4,c+=a
set /a d=4*c+3,d/=1461,e=-1461*d,e/=4,e+=c,m=5*e+2,m/=153,dd=153*m+2,dd/=5
set /a dd=-dd+e+1,mm=-m/10,mm*=12,mm+=m+3,yy=b*100+d-4800+m/10
(if %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%)&(if %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%)
endlocal&set %3=%yy%&set %4=%mm%&set %5=%dd%&goto :EOF
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: See edit. How come that `The system cannot find the batch label specified - OrdinalToDate` error is showing when it doesn't appear on the first calculation? And as well as the `Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script.`?

Answer (score 1):

**Reference** [Call](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

> **CALL a subroutine (:label)**
>
> The CALL command will pass control to the statement after the label
>   specified along with any specified parameters. To exit the subroutine
>   specify GOTO:eof this will transfer control to the end of the current
>   subroutine.
>
> A label is defined by a single colon followed by a name. This is the
>   basis of a batch file function.
>
> ```
> CALL :sub_display 123
> CALL :sub_display 456
> ECHO All Done
> GOTO :eof
>
> :sub_display
> ECHO The result is %1
> GOTO :eof
> ```
>
> At the end of the subroutine, GOTO :eof will return to the position
>   where you used CALL.
>
> **Command blocks do not work with the call command. Redirection with & | <> also does not work as expected.**

**Reference** [Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html):

> Parenthesis can be used to split commands across multiple lines. This
>   can make code more readable. Variables will be evaluated for the code
>   block just as if the command was a single line.
>
> ```
>   (command)
>
>   (
>     command
>     command )
> ```
>
> Example
>
> IF EXIST C:\pagefile.sys (
>           ECHO pagefile found on C: drive)
>
> **If the command will fit on a single line, then the parenthesis can be
>   omitted**

You have the following command block inside your call block:

```
(if %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%)&(if %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%)
```

...

> **A GOTO command inside a bracketed code block will break the
>   parenthesis context and cause errors. A GOTO will also break a For-Do
>   Loop.**

I believe `call` works like `goto`. So `(` ... `call...` ... `)` could be your problem.

Why don't you make `OrdinalToDate` a seperate batch file?

Comment: Then you have a different problem. Please try to create a **small* reproducible test script. Edit you question to include the new information.

Comment: I wasn't able to cd to the input path that is why it resulted to `file not found`. Sorry about that. Now when I added the input_path the error was this `'OrdinalToDate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: So I made the OrdinalToDate a separate batch file. I just add a @echo off and saved it as OrdinalToDate.bat. Then from the call batch file, I just change it to call OrdinalToDate.bat. And inserted endlocal after the gdal_calculate command and the result was `'OrdinalToDate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: If you have a `cd` first you need to make sure `OrdinalToDate.bat` is on your path or use a fully quealified name when you call it ...

Comment: I already made sure that the batch file is on the right path, and changed the batch name into `ordinal.bat`. When I run the batch file, only the first file from the input path was processed the rest was failed. It says `'ordinal.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` And `RuntimeError: D:\Sample\sample_file_.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.` And `RuntimeError: D:\Sample\sample_file_!Month!.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.`

Comment: Then you have a different problem. Please try to create a *small reproducible test script. Edit your question to include the new information.

Comment: What do you think might be the problem?

Comment: I've no idea :/

Comment: Just want to ask if I have a 64-bit os and I've installed 32-bit python, 32-bit gdal, and 32- bit gdal_calculate and all other libraries, will that affect the whole script? Or maybe one of the reason to cause an error?

Comment: 32 bit should not be a problem.